# import CSV to MySQL error

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I'm trying to import 5 columns of data from a CSV to MySQL table.  The first column of the MySQL is autoincrement, the first column of the CSV is blank.  The following code produces an error.

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

database = MySQLdb.connect(host='10.200.10.125', user='spaine', passwd='spaine', db='scat')
cursor = database.cursor()


cursor.execute('show tables')
for row in cursor:
    print row

cursor.execute('describe brewpubs')
print "\n info about table brewpubs"

for row in cursor:
    print row

csv_file = 'E:\\Proving Grounds\\MsSQL Connection\\Brewery Data\\Breweries.csv'
csv_data = csv.reader(file(csv_file))


for row in csv_data:
    print row
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO brewpubs (PID, name, londd, latdd, desc) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''', row)


database.commit()  # Make sure data is committed to the database

database.close()
```

This code produces the following error:
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc) VALUES('', 'Hoppy Brewing', '-121.429684', '38.554962', 'http://www.hoppy.' at line 1")

Comment: where did you see `file(csv_file)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

desc is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in mysql, you have to enclose it by backticks (`) to use it as an identifier:

```
... (PID, name, londd, latdd, `desc`)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column is auto increment omit it from the insert entirely since it is always blank.

Comment: How would you omit it since its the first column?